why weak topology is weaker than norm topology
Arguments written in books are always as follows

Weak topology is weaker than norm topology since every sequence which converges in norm topology converges in weak topology.

Convergence of sequence in weak topology follows from the fact that $f(x)\leq ||f||\cdot||x||$ for every $x\in X, f\in X^*$. But weak topology being weaker than norm topology is by definition that every open set in weak topology is open in norm topology. How do I deduce this knowing the fact about sequences?

Technically, “sequence” should be replaced by “net”. After that, use the fact that a set is open iff its complement is closed; and a set is closed iff every convergent net of elements of the set has its limit(s) contained in the set.

You can only necessarily use sequences if your space is, for example, metrizable fwiw. The convergent nets of a topological space characterise the topology, (a set in a topological space is a neighborhood of $x$ iff it contains a tail of every net converging to $x$)  but the convergent sequences do not necessarily. E.g. consider the discrete and co-countable topologies on $\mathbb R$ - they have the same convergent sequences, and the proof of this inescapably relies on the countability of the indexing set so doesn't apply to general nets.
